# Add content to Web Part without reloading

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, wss-3.0, asp.net

I am developing a Search Web Part for a WSS 3.0 site in Visual Studio 2008. The user types in their search criteria, then clicks OK. In the Click event, I am iterating through every Site Collection in the current Web Application and showing all information that matches the search. What I would like to do, is show one line at a time, such as "Searching xxx", until that site has been searched, then show the results for that site. Then I would continue with the next site. Currently, nothing is displayed until all sites have been searched.

The whole point is, I want the user to see periodic results on the page while they are waiting. What is the best way to dynamically update a Web Part during a long operation?

Comment: Why can't you just query the search index itself?  This would be almost instant and eliminate the need for this entirely

Comment: Because the search index does not do what I want, in any way. For one thing, it only searches entire words. If this post was in a SharePoint list, and I search for "Appl" or "Cigar", it would return no results. Only if I search for "Application" or "CigarDoug", would it return this post. What happens when a user only knows part of a serial number? Also, I want to display the results within a Web Part on the page, and not take the user to another page to see results. Also, I want to customize how the search results look, what columns are returned. That is why.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a javascript timer and an update panel or icallbackeventhandler to update the content on the screen every 5 seconds or so.

Comment: Would this work within a click event?

Comment: I don't see why not.